# How to change this wrap-region configuration on the init file from the classic imperative installation to a declarative approach via use-package?

Tags: package, use-package, wrapping, wrap-region

When I first installed [wrap-region](https://github.com/rejeep/wrap-region.el), I used to install things via the classic `M-x` and `package-install`. Then, I inserted the following configuration:

```lisp
;; Emacs minor mode to wrap region with tag or punctuations
(wrap-region-mode 1)
(wrap-region-add-wrapper "*" "*")
(wrap-region-add-wrapper "/" "/")
(wrap-region-add-wrapper "=" "=")
```

This used to work out. Now, I have moved to a new machine and I have not used classic installation yet (`M-x` and `package-install`).

I want to do everything via [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package).

I am especially unsure about how to make the mode globally enabled.

This is my first attempt:

```lisp
(use-package wrap-region
  :ensure t
  :config
    (wrap-region-mode 1)
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "*" "*")
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "/" "/")
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "=" "="))
```

The wrapper expressions (function call with `wrap-region-add-wrapper`) are working as expected.

However, the mode is **not** being globally enabled when Emacs starts.

How would you convert the declaration previously mentioned to a complete `use-package` declarative installation?

Comment: `I am especially unsure about how to handle the expressions creating the "pattern-matching"` - what pattern matching are you talking about? Not clear to me (but I know close to nothing about `use-package` OR `wrap-region` - so it's not clear to me whether it refers to `use-package` or `wrap-region` -or neither - or both).

Comment: As for expecting it to be globally enabled, why would it? Isn't that what `wrap-region-global-mode` is for?

Comment: Thanks, @NickD. Maybe I misunderstood `(wrap-region-mode t)`.  What do I need to do to enable it globally?     And, I am calling the following a "pattern matching"? `    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "*" "*")`. Maybe it was a bad term.

Comment: `(wrap-region-global-mode 1)` should do the global enablement. Do `C-h f wrap-region-mode` and `C-h f wrap-region-global-mode` for more details.  See `Defining minor modes` for additional insight: do `C-h i g(elisp) RET m defining minor modes` to get there.

Comment: I think "pattern-matching" is a bad term for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What is your suggestion for this word?    I am not a native speaker of English. My English vocabulary is probably not as good as yours.

Comment: AFAICT, it's a `wrap-region` thing and they call it a `wrapper`, so why not call it that?

Comment: So if you change the config to `(wrap-region-global-mode 1)`, do you still see problems? Or does that resolve everything? Do you have problems with the wrappers? It's not clear to me what is and what is not a problem.

Comment: @NickD, thanks for the help.  (i) Although I have `(wrap-region-mode 1)` written in the config file, the mode is not being globally enabled. For instance, I opened a new `.org` file, but `wrap-region-mode` is not among the minor modes enabled. After doing `C-h m`, I can double check it is not enabled. We need to solve this! (ii) On the wrappers, they work as expected after I enable the wrap-region-mode.

Comment: Please reread my comment: I'm asking about `wrap-region-global-mode`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo I made. Everything works as expected. Thank you. I will post the answer mentioning your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @NickD's help, I realized there was a missing word of `global` on  `wrap-region-mode`.

The correct is:

```lisp
(wrap-region-global-mode 1)
```

And the final expression:

```lisp
(use-package wrap-region
  :ensure t
  :config
    (wrap-region-global-mode 1)
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "*" "*")
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "/" "/")
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "=" "="))
```